# How can I prevent unbound from restarting?

Tags: internal-dns, unbound

I'm running unbound version 1.4.22

Every time I run `pon` or `poff` (PPPoE connections) unbound restarts, as seen in the unbound logfile. I easily confirm this is the case by repeating a DNS query that was cached just before I ran `poff`

Every time it restarts it clears all of the DNS records that it had cached previously. This is unnecessary and a huge waste.

There is nothing in my unbound conf file that should cause this.

I have specifically ensured that I am not binding on the ppp0 interface.
I have
`interface: 127.0.0.1`
`interface: 192.168.5.5`

Answer (score 1):

usepeerdns must be disabled in the pppoe connection script.